# Random walk on d dimensional torus, martingale

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation, martingales, random-walk

I am reading the following paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.03849v2.pdf

I will explain the general setup below.

Let $x\in X=\mathbb{T}^d$, where $\mathbb{T}^d$ is the d dimensional torus. Let $\rho$ be a Borel prob. measure on SL$_d(\mathbb{Z})$, and set $X_0=x$, and $X_{n+1}=g_{n+1}X_n$ where $(g_n)\subset$ SL$_d(\mathbb{Z})$ is chosen with law $\rho^{\otimes\mathbb{N}}$. 
Let $\mathbb{P}_x$ be the measure on $X^\mathbb{N}$ associated with the random walk starting at $x$.

For $f$ Borel on $X$, $f\geq 0$, and $x\in X$, define the Markov operator $Pf(x)=\int_{SL_d(\mathbb{Z})}f(gx)d\rho(g).$
We have $\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_n)]=\mathbb{E}_x[P^{n-k}f(X_k)]$ for all $k\leq n$. We let $g$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{T}^d$.
Let $M_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}g(X_{k+1})-Pg(X_k)$. I want to show $M_n$ is a martingale wrt $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_k \mid k\leq n)$.. It is easy to see this is equivalent to showing that 
$\mathbb{E}[g(X_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_n]=Pg(X_n)$.

This is the part which I am having trouble with. Any help would be much appreciated! 
(I think the Markov property is used somewhere).

Edit: My attempt so far: By the Markov property, it suffices to show $\mathbb{E}[g(X_{n+1}) \mid X_n]=Pg(X_n)$.

Clearly $Pg(X_n)$ is $\sigma(X_n)$ measurable.
So it remains to show $\int Pg(X_n)d\mu_{X_n}=\int g(X_{n+1})d\mu_{X_n}$. This part I am having trouble with. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $g_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n(=\sigma(g_1,\ldots,g_n))$. Therefore
$$
\eqalign{
\Bbb E[G(X_{n+1})\,|\,\mathcal F_n]
&=\Bbb E[G(g_{n+1}X_{n})\,|\,\mathcal F_n]\cr
&=\int_{SL_d(\Bbb Z)}G(gX_n)\,d\rho(g)\cr
&=PG(X_n)}.
$$

Comment: Actually, a comment: Why is $g_{n+1}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$? The $g_n$ were not chosen independently.

Comment: Because $X_k=g_kg_{k-1}\cdots g_1 x$ , $\mathcal F_n\subset\sigma(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$, and $g_{n+1}$ is independent of the latter $\sigma$-field.

Comment: The question is, why is $g_{n+1}$ independent of the latter $\sigma$-field?